# Am I really exceeding the Anylogic PLE agent count?

Tags: anylogic

I seem to be exceeding the number of dynamically created agents for my model, but I have only generated 15 agents out of 30 (as seen in screenshot) from my source when this message pops up:

**Error**
[image]

**Model Logic:**
A linked list (LLTable) containing data of a schedule is created from a spreadsheet. Agents are injected by an event which randomly chooses from the linked list, and assigns a source and a target conveyor to each load. This event recurs every 0.833/30 hours and stops generating when the number loads generated hits 30.

Respectively, the loads are generated at their conveyors and sent to their target conveyors by the MoveByTransporter block. My transporter fleet consists of 400 transporters.

**Load**
[image]

**My Model and Excel File**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Pmt0KX0VLdmWXrPCwZr7_h0Dp3UIUTfh/view

The excel file is the From To Schedule that can be changed from time to time. he rate of agents entering the system is influenced by the total number in this file. However for simplicity, i have just made the event rate to be 0.8333/30 since 0.8333/500 is not working.

Comment: do you have agents generated inside loads or inside transporters? And what are you showing here? you already have 100 loads and 100 transporters... so I see 215 agents generated, but you are not showing us everything

Comment: Hi Felipe, apologies for the lack of information. I forgot to delete the 100 loads and transporters; that was not part of the code. I included more information through screenshots and brief explanation of the model code. If you need slightly more information, here is the model: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EDlGwRSS_XXWoVe1P0HvDkpD6co8nF4j

Comment: you didn't upload all the files so I can't help you out

Comment: Hi @Felipe, here is the link for the zip file, drive.google.com/open?id=1Pmt0KX0VLdmWXrPCwZr7_h0Dp3UIUTfh! Appreciate your help :)

Comment: @Felipe would you be so kind as to take a second look on my model? Really appreciate it!